# Meta refresh on current domain

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to refresh page on the domain that it has been opened on, website can be accessed from multiple domains so I want to use the current one.

I tried

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . "/p.php" . "\">";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="; echo $url;
```

But that redirects me to: p.php without any domain, same result using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why not just use `header()`?

Comment: `header("Location: page.php"); exit;` redirection done

Comment: I want to blank refers / set new ones, does that work with header() ?

Comment: @MariusProllak Test it and find out

Comment: Whut!?! Redirect using a http refresh. This is soo bad practice, you will never learn PHP proper this way... `header("Location: /p.php");`

Comment: I'm perfectly capable of using a header redirect with php thanks :)

Comment: I guess not... else you would use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any `$_SERVER` value. Just:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/p.php">
```

The browser will use the same domain as the one it's currently visiting when it constructs the complete URL to which to redirect itself.

Comment: @MariusProllak Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little long for your taste but here it is

```
    // find out the domain:
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    // find out the path to the current file:
    $path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    // find out the QueryString:
    $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    //Add parameters if any
    if (!empty($queryString)) {
    $queryString = "?" . $queryString;
    }
    // put it all together:
    $url = "http://" . $domain . $path . $queryString;
    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $url; ?>"
```